# The proper way to insert an image in memory into Webview in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, image, webview, core-plot

I have an image of a graph generated using the Core-Plot framework. I'd like to be able to insert the image into a custom report which is held in a Webview.

Is there an advised or best practise way of doing this. i.e. if the image needs to be saved to disk as a temporay file, where should the image be placed? When should the image be deleted etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you control all the html that's to be rendered in the webview, I'd suggest saving a sort of local web archive, with the html, image and any other resources all in the same place, making your custom report's rendering much less prone to breaking. (You could even make it a supported bundle document type, if you get that far along.)

If you just need to have the file available for a one-time rendering of a modified html document, I suggest using the NSTemporaryDirectory() path:

```
NSData        *imageData = ...;
NSString      *temporaryImagePath = NSTemporaryDirectory();
NSError       *error = nil;

temporaryImagePath = [ temporaryImagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"img.jpg" ];
[ imageData writeToFile: temporaryImagePath options: NSDataWritingAtomic error: &error ];
```